# Angular - @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) doesn't allow property access

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, modal-dialog

I'm injecting data of type `Sequence` into a modal

```
  openDialog(head: Sequence) {
    this.dialog.open(ModalAsTreeComponent, {
      width: '90%',
      height: '580px',
      maxHeight: '100vh',
      maxWidth: '100vw',
      data: {
        sequence
      }
    });
  }
```

This is the interface:

```
import { TreeNode } from './treeNode';
export interface Sequence{
  id: string;
  prefix: string;
  rRC: number;
  collectorPeer: {
    peerBGPId: number;
    peerIPAddress: string;
    peerAS: number;
  };
  start: string;
  end: string;
  runID: string;
  longestCommonAsPathSuffix: number;
  asPathNumber: number;
  asOrigins: number;
  hasAggregator: boolean;
  containsAsPathLoops: boolean;
  containsLoops: boolean;
  mostFrequentUpdateFrequency: number;
  mostFrequentUpdateFrequencyInMin: number;
  hasAsPathsNotValid: boolean;
  asTreeWithoutAggregator: {
    head: TreeNode;
  };
  announces: number;
  withdraws: number;
  updates: number;
  duration: string;
  frequency: number;
}
```

I inject the data into the modal and I console.log it:

```
export class ModalAsTreeComponent implements OnInit {

  ...
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Sequence) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log(this.data);
  }
```

Everything is fine, data is shown in the console and I can see every value of each property. The problem resides in trying to access any of these properties. If I try to console.log any of this properties, let's say the property announces, `console.log(this.data.announces)` gives undefined which doesn't seem to make sense because `console.log(this.data)` gave all the data including the value of announces. There seems to be a problem with accessing the properties of the original injected data.
This is the original result of `console.log(this.data)`

```
announces: 732493
asOrigins: [31424]
asPathNumber: 12
asTreeWithoutAggregator: {head: {…}}
collectorPeer: {peerBGPId: 0, peerIPAddress: "2a07:a40::", peerAS: 48821}
containsAsPathLoops: true
containsLoops: false
duration: "84.22:53:52"
end: "2019-03-26T22:53:52Z"
frequency: 0.09979425157819476
hasAggregator: false
hasAsPathsNotValid: false
id: "5ee56984a62b68061ce5b638"
longestCommonAsPathSuffix: 1
mostFrequentUpdateFrequency: 176682
mostFrequentUpdateFrequencyInMin: 1.4442607334681918
prefix: "2a0d:8d80::/32"
rRC: 0
runID: "RRC00-v6"
start: "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"
updates: 732493
withdraws: 0
```

Needless to say that I can't work with undefined values

Comment: Where are you trying to access `this.data.announces`? It's probably an async operation so you might need to adjust your code accordingly

Comment: I'm doing it all in the ngOnInit(), both `console.log(this.data)` and `console.log(this.data.announces)`

Comment: sure but where do you actually want to use it? Probably in the html, right?

Comment: yes, but I still haven't gotten to that point, I'm still trying to model the data I will then show in the html.

Comment: Ok your code is fine. The main reason why you might be getting `undefined` is that probably the modal opening and injecting the data is async. Don't trust the chrome console because it will show the value after it is defined for non-primitive types (like objects). If you use that data in your html like `<span>{{data?.announces}}</span>` I believe it will work

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, it works only if I inject `data.announces` directly into the modal. The problems start whenever I access the properties of the originally injected data

Comment: @MaurizioBrini What if you try with `this.dialog.open(ModalAsTreeComponent, {
..., data: sequence });` without brackets ?

Comment: @Emilien Oh god it works! Thank you so much. If you want you can post an answer and I can mark it as correct

Comment: @MaurizioBrini Perfect ! I've added it as an answer, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass your object, without wrapping it into another object.

So it would look like :

```js
this.dialog.open(ModalAsTreeComponent, {
  width: '90%',
  height: '580px',
  maxHeight: '100vh',
  maxWidth: '100vw',
  data: sequence
});
```